# Having trouble executing the user id session after user logs in

Tags: php, html, session, mysqli

Here is the following codes i have so far for the sign up page login page and homepage. note i am only posting the php I know everything is working except for the user id session. I am connected to my database and row 1 is id and is the primary key.

## here is the signup php

```
<?php
require ("func/insert.php");

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['first_name']);
        $last_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['last_name']);
        $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['email']);
        $password= $_POST ['password'];

        $StorePassword= password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));

        $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO users ( first_name, last_name, email, password)
                    VALUES ( ' {$first_name} ' , ' {$last_name} ' , ' {$email} ' , ' {$StorePassword} ' )");
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
?>
```

## HEre is the login php

```
<?php require ("func/insert.php"); ?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Login']))
    {
    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($con, $_POST ['email']));
    $password= mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($con, $_POST ['password']));

    $result = $con->query(" select * from users where email='$email' AND password='$password' ");

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['id']; //thinking this is the problem
    header ('Location: home.php');
    }
```

## And here is the home php

```
<?php require ("func/insert.php"); ?>
<?php
session_start(); 
    if (isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) {
}
else {
echo "This session is not working.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Does that `select` query work properly? So can you `echo` results? If not then you've found your issue.

Comment: You should try to log what `$row` contains or whether this line is processed: `if(isset($_POST['Login']))`

Comment: Why do you do `<?php require ("func/insert.php"); ?>` then reopen the `PHP` tags? Why not just include the `require` with the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are comparing the stored and hashed password again a non-hashed password.

in Login.php
This line set's your password:

```
$password= mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($con, $_POST ['password']));
```

And then it is compared to the password that is stored in the database.  However that password has been hashed in signup.php

```
    $StorePassword= password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
```

Try hashing the incoming password in sign in.

```
$TryPassword= password_hash($_POST ['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
```

And then the SQL:

```
$result = $con->query(" select * from users where email='$email' AND password='$TryPassword' ");
```

Before redirecting to the next page, debug it by making sure you returned a row!

```
print_r($result);
```